# Zoom to selection

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to create an application, where in I want to zoom to selected features. Basically, I want to zoom to the extent of a selected point or polygon.

Comment: I am trying to do this in javascript.

Answer (score 6):

Try this will work for you

```
function ZoomToSelection() {
      graphics = new esri.Graphic();
      var taxLotExtent;
  graphics = featureLayer.getSelectedFeatures();
      taxLotExtent = graphics[0].geometry.getExtent();
  map.setExtent(taxLotExtent);
  }
```

Comment: The above one is for single feature for multiple features use **esri.geometry.Extent(pass the individual geometry extent by iterating)**. You will get the resultant Extent of the selected fetures.

Comment: You can't just iterate since you will then zoom to each individual feature in succession.  You need to merge all the extents then zoom to the resulting extent.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the java is not far from this (this is C#) but the principles are the same. Query the selection extents, union them, bump the result by a factor, and show it.

```js
// passing in ActiveView 
// passing in targetLayer
// ZOOM_FACTOR = 1.5 
// ensure we have selected features
IFeatureSelection featureSelection = targetLayer as IFeatureSelection;
if (featureSelection == null) return;

ISelectionSet selectionSet = featureSelection.SelectionSet;

using (ComReleaser comReleaser = new ComReleaser())
{
    // search for each selection
    ICursor cursor;
    selectionSet.Search(null, true, out cursor);
    comReleaser.ManageLifetime(cursor);

    // build an envelope containing a union of the selections
    IFeatureCursor featureCursor = cursor as IFeatureCursor;
    IFeature feature;
    IEnvelope envelope = new EnvelopeClass();
    while ((feature = featureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
    {
        IGeometry geometry = feature.Shape;
        IEnvelope featureExtent = geometry.Envelope;
        envelope.Union(featureExtent);
    }

    if (!envelope.IsEmpty)
    {
        // set the extent
        envelope.Expand(ZOOM_FACTOR, ZOOM_FACTOR, true);
        view.Extent = envelope;
        view.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by calling getSelectedFeatures() on your Feature Layer (big assumption that this is a graphics or feature layer, am i correct here?) and then iterating through the returned array of Graphic objects. If the features are polygons, then the geometry property will have a getExtent() method. Just keep track of the extreme lat/lng values and set the map extent to these once you've checked all of the selected features. I'm a little confused by your mention of 'point and polygon' because I thought feature classes had to be one type or the other. Are you trying to zoom in on a group of features selected from two different sets? This would be a little trickier but should still be achievable by a similar method.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [graphicUtils.graphicsExtent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.graphicsutils-amd.html#graphicsextent)

Simply pass in the array of graphics and you will get the extent.

Answer (score 0):

To zoom at particular feature, you need a geometry of the feature.

```
var geometry = selectedFeature.geometry;
zoomToFeature: function (geometry) {
  this.map.setExtent(geometry.getExtent());
};
```

[Esri documentation of extent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#extent)