# Zooming to selection on ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, zoom

I am using the latest ArcGIS Javascript API. All the examples and code I've found so far only deal with geometries of a `FeatureLayer`.

How do I zoom to the visible features of an `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` or an `ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer` layer?

By visible I mean that some of the features of the layers are filtered out thanks to the `layerDefinitions` property.

I wish I could keep using FeatureLayers but I can't because I am running in to a wall due the sheer amount of geometry data downloaded, so I have to let the server do the rendering work and use a `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` to get images instead.

Comment: You can try to create graphic  layer and then try zoom to functionality .Please check out http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21134/zoom-to-selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't possible and you'll need to work with the features in order to zoom to the combined extent of the query/definition.

(answer from ArcGIS Forums http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/83910-How-to-zoom-to-selection-on-ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer)